# how to add custom view in a middle of base view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have created custom language view. I want that view show on a middle of center of iPad. 
Here is what I have

```
static let langView = UINib(nibName: "LanguagesListView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! LanguagesListView

  func languagesPopup() -> Void {
        BaseVC.langView.delegate = self
        BaseVC.langView.frame = self.view.bounds
        BaseVC.langView.center = CGPoint(x:self.view.frame.size.width  / 2, y:
                                        self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
        self.view.addSubview(BaseVC.langView)
    }
```

When I call this method it shows somewhere in the left.

Comment: Just as a quick thing to check, did you try adding it as a subview of `self.view`?

Comment: Have you tried setting `BaseVC.langView.center = self.view.center`?

Comment: I did. It's not working

Comment: try
BaseVC.langView.bounds = self.view.bounds
instead of BaseVC.langView.frame = self.view.bounds
may be this could help.

Comment: @Tan No it did not helped as well

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the frame of your langView equals to bounds of your root view, so the position x, position y, width and height will be same of your root view. If the width of langView is same of parent view your view always will be in left side. Try set different size for your langView. Try something like this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewT = UIView()

        viewT.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        viewT.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        viewT.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(viewT)

    }
```

Comment: When you call this function?

Comment: Do you tried to replace `BaseVC.langView.frame = self.view.bounds` to `BaseVC.langView.frame.size = CGSize (width: 50, height: 50)` ?